# gem2rpm includes all dependencies instead of including only runtime dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, rpm

Version 0.6.0 of gem2rpm includes all (development and runtime) dependencies for a given Gem.

Example: Rack Gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/rack) Version 1.1.0 has no runtime dependencies, but six development
dependencies.

Console output of `gem2rpm --dependencies rack-1.0.1.gem` is:

- rubygem(test-spec) >= 0
- rubygem(camping) >= 0
- rubygem(fcgi) >= 0
- rubygem(memcache-client) >= 0
- rubygem(mongrel) >= 0
- rubygem(ruby-openid) >= 2.0.0
- rubygem(thin) >= 0`

How can I specify to only include runtime dependencies?

I have also opened a ticket on [rubyforge.org](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=27967&group_id=3780&atid=14602), but there isn't a lot of activity on that tracker.

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sender: Miguel Armas

I also suffered from this bug. I corrected it including only
dependencies of type :runtime with the following patch:

```
--
--- gem2rpm.rb.orig 2010-04-08 00:09:39.794856454 +0100
+++ gem2rpm.rb  2010-04-08 00:27:11.808853058 +0100
@@ -105,10 +105,12 @@
 BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u}-n)
 Requires: rubygems
 <% for d in spec.dependencies %>
+<% if d.type == :runtime %>
 <% for req in d.version_requirements.to_rpm %>
 Requires: rubygem(<%= d.name %>) <%= req  %>
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
+<% end %>
 BuildRequires: rubygems
 <% if spec.extensions.empty? %>
 BuildArch: noarch
--
```

I didn't include the :development dependencies as BuildRequires
because they are not needed to create the RPM from the SRPM

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed about 4 months later here : https://github.com/lutter/gem2rpm/commit/10e8f80da8fa5dfcdd5e5800f72106f0b995a6e5 so updating to a newer version of gem2rpm will address this.